# How to secure sensitive information PHP file?

Tags: php, linux

I have a file, which contains encryption keys, database passwords, basically sensitive data.

The file is being opened by PHP processor, in order to get the required information.

It is also on the linux filesystem, out of the web server directories, for security reasons.

Is there any way this file to be somehow direct-access secured or encrypted, in order to prevent attacker's eyes?

Whatever I try, if the attacker gets SSH access, he will be able to direct access it, or view it using the PHP processor.

Comment: What is the point of having the file outside of the web server directory if you're accessing it with the web server

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I guess he meant web root directory to prevent it from being web accessible and given you can include the file with any other PHP file within the root it would not matter in that way.

Comment: @Prix Exactly. IMHO, PHP is the most insecure language in the world, and not just because there are developers who leave their code wide open. I remember a time when adding `?-s` to a URL showed you the source code of the file in question. Don't get me wrong, I love PHP, but it should not be used when security is eminent.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy every single language in the world is insecure there is too many ways to look at the code, best that can be done is make it difficult for people to access it, be it using IDA, Olly, deobfuscating or whatever method is required reversing is well known and unhappily affect every language out there. In the end it comes down to how popular your code is and how easy to crack it is before you see it going around for free.

Comment: I don't see does it matter, but okay, ignore the webserver thing. The question is quite different. Do anyone have some ideas? I was thinking about fully Ioncube encoding, but it seems that it's possible for attackers to decode it.

Comment: Are you going to sell your code? are people going to use it else where but on your own server? are people going to have access to it?

Comment: No, it's not for selling. When I think of it, the SSH will be opened only for my IP address. But still, I'm worried is it possible for a hacker to access it somehow.

Comment: @thexer Here is some info that may help you, [Can a hacker hack a website's FTP, SSH and/or .htaccess file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245087/can-a-hacker-hack-a-websites-ftp-ssh-and-or-htaccess-file/18245333#18245333). Securing a server is a daily thing you will need a good Server Administrator if you want to keep everything secure and up to date there is a lot of things that needs to be done in order to make sure your server is safe and its not only server side its also code wise if your code is poorly done and have for instance things that would allow SQL Injection or others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think encryption makes very little sense, since you'll have to store the key in the same environment als the values. There are multiple ways to read the file from an attack vector. Other wise the approach is common practice, and pretty secure, as long as you can guarantee the security of your php ecosystem.

### 1. Filesystem level

Be sure about what you're doing with the permissions of the file, this will be the main source of insecurities. Make sure that the file is owned by the user under which php runs. Hopefully this is under one specific user for the project, and the file will have permissions like chmod 600 for only that user).

If this is not the case:
Everything that can read the file (e.g. in an insecure shared hosting environment without something suphp). Also any other process that has access to php has in this scenario access to the file. If there would be for example an wordpress installation that is outdated - and can open any php injection, it would be possible to read the file. (there are other configuration options that will make this difficult)

### 2. Server level

Are the any other users on the server? If so, what servers are running on the server? Would they be able to read the file?

### 3. Php level

Do you have any scripts that might be tricked into reading the file, and outputting its content? Making sure that other scripts/ applications that run this file are up to date and secure.

See also:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks, the links are very useful and informative also.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if PHP needs the sensitive data, you're not going to be able to encrypt it in any meaningful way.

Encryption/Decryption always requires some form of human interaction to be fully secure (ie the supply of a passphrase with a private key).

The best you can do is to ensure that your server is protected by requiring human interaction to decrypt access (eg Only allowing shell access based on OpenSSH key pairs).

You could also introduce a few layers of obfuscation, so that in the event the shell is compromised, the intruder would still have work to do.